# Ruby in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I am trying to feed a Rails path into a JavaScript.

It looks a bit like this

view.html.erb

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      grid.load("/users/:user_id/actions/:action_id/tasks/data.xml");
    </script>
```

However, this obviously does not actually actively feed in the :user_id's and :action_id's. Is there a way to embed ruby into this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helper methods generated by your routes, assuming you've given your routes sensible names:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  grid.load("<%= user_actions_tasks_data_path(@user, @action) %>");
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure to JSON-encode any variable data being injected into JavaScript from the server.